# OpenLayers 2.13.1: deleting a geometry from a multigeometry feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers

For example I have a multipolygon consisting of two polygons. I can delete vertices with the modifyFeature control and the delete-key. However, the modifyFeature control does not allow me to delete a polygon completely because it has to contain at least 3 vertices. How do I delete a polygon completely from a multipolygon feature (with the delete-key)? Is there an appropriate control or a plugin available for OpenLayers?

I tried it myself with patching the control but that resulted in multiple minor bugs. So I thought I ask first if someone already did that before I spend a lot of time to fix the issues.

Comment: You are looking for a delete feature on select control?

Answer (score 0):

```
removeComponent: function(point) {
    var removed = this.components && (this.components.length > 3);
    if (removed) {
        //remove last point
        this.components.pop();

        //remove our point
        OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection.prototype.removeComponent.apply(this, 
                                                                arguments);
        //append copy of first point
        var firstPoint = this.components[0];
        OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection.prototype.addComponent.apply(this, 
                                                            [firstPoint]);
    //bm extension: possibility to delete geometry from multigeometries
    } else if (this.components && this.parent && this.parent.parent && this.parent.parent.CLASS_NAME === "OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon") {        
        //polygon with hole
        if (this.parent.components.length > 1) {              
            for (var i = 0; i < this.parent.components.length && this.parent.components.length > 1; i++) {
                if (this.parent.components[i].id === this.id) {
                    OpenLayers.Util.removeItem(this.parent.components, this.parent.components[i]);
                    this.parent.clearBounds();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //seperate polygon
        for (var i = 0; i < this.parent.parent.components.length && this.parent.parent.components.length > 1; i++) {
            if (this.parent.parent.components[i].id === this.parent.id) {
                OpenLayers.Util.removeItem(this.parent.parent.components, this.parent.parent.components[i]);
                this.parent.parent.clearBounds();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return removed;
},
```

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your question. Multipolygon has nothing to do with it, it is simply deleting beyond 3 points.